# peeking in scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

`enter code here`Just need to know the basics of peeking in scheme. I tried looking at the racket site for help but it didn't have much on it. Or maybe I was looking in the wrong section. Anyways, the point of this is the following.

if I have
(#\x #\b #\o #\x #\space #\3 #\6 #\0)

I want to be able to identify x as a char and then continue peeking until space is reached and redefine this as a word. Then do the same for 360.

Any tips? 
Please and thank you! : )

Here is what my code looks like in case it helps

```
(define (work x) 
(cond
((null? x)(write '$$))
(char-numeric? (car x))
(write 'Num)
(toke (cdr x)))
((char-alphabetic? (car x))
(write 'ID)
(work (cdr x)))
(else (write "other")))
```

The problem with this is that it would give me IDIDIDID for "xbox" (which makes sense cause of the code) but I want to make it output just ID once for the whole word xbox

Comment: What is "peeking"? What do you mean by redefining #\space as a word? And what do you want to do with the numbers? The list in your question is made up of characters,  #\space #\3 #\6 #\0 are all characters. It'd be better if you write explicitly the expected output for the given input.

Comment: What I meant by this is the following, 
If I have (#\x #\b #\o #\x #\space #\3 #\6 #\0) I want to be able to write out that xbox is a word and 360 is a number. 
The point of this is to analyze the first character and if it is alphabetic then I use peek-char till I hit a space or end of file. This way I can say that the word is xbox, not x is a word, b is a word, o is a word, x is a word. 
I read about peek-char somewhere online, the racket site doesn't have much on it. 
Do I explain myself?

Comment: We need more context.  Is your input a byte-string? Is this part of a homework project? Is there some reason you can't just use regular expressions?

Comment: If I could I would use regexps but I can't. Yes it's for a homework project. The purpose is to create a scanner. I'm almost there, just having problems with identifying IDs. 
Let's see if I can clarify further. 
I have
(define str (string #\x #\b #\o #\x #\space #\3 #\6 #\0))
(define list 
(string->list str))

Comment: Now I want to go through the list of chars and be able to write out the word together as a string and not just as single chars. I know I can do this by peek-char till I reach a space or eof. Once I reach this space or eof I can take that substring beginning from the first char that I analyzed as a char-alphabetical up until the point where space or eof is found and output it into a list.

Comment: All I'm asking for is tips on how peek-char works. If I can figure that out then I can figure out how to write the code. Believe me I am at the library looking through books and my partner is looking online while we're posting these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are simpler ways to solve the problem, but they involve some extra knowledge of the language. For instance, using [regular expressions](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/regexp.html) for splitting a string at the spaces and [`map` and `filter`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html) for processing each word:

```
(define line "xbox 360")

(define (process line)
  (map (lambda (word)
         (cond ((string->number word) "number")
               (else "word")))
       (filter (lambda (str)
                 (not (equal? str "")))
               (regexp-split #px"\\s+" line))))
```

Notice that the input received was a *string* containing a line in the input file (as returned by the procedure `file->lines`). The general idea would be: read the file line by line, and process each one in turn with the above snippet of code.

If you're ok with using functionality a bit more advanced in your code, the above will do the trick.

**EDIT :**

I wrote a version using only list iteration and `read-char` (not `peek-char`, which reads only the first char and doesn't advance to the next one), but you'll see that this is far more complex to understand than the above procedure:

```
(define (process line)
  (let ((port (open-input-string line)))
    (let loop ((char (read-char port))
               (acc  '()))
      (cond ((eof-object? char)
             (cond ((null? acc) '())
                   ((string->number (list->string acc)) (list "number"))
                   (else (list "word"))))
            ((char-whitespace? char)
             (cond ((null? acc)
                    (loop (read-char port) '()))
                   ((string->number (list->string acc))
                    (cons "number" (loop (read-char port) '())))
                   (else
                    (cons "word"   (loop (read-char port) '())))))
            (else
             (loop (read-char port) (cons char acc)))))))
```

Both solutions work as expected for the following tests:

```
(process "xbox 360")
> '("word" "number")

(process "1")
> '("number")

(process "a")
> '("word")

(process " ")
> '()

(process "")
> '()

(process "  a  b  1 a   ")
> '("word" "word" "number" "word")
```

Comment: Thanks Oscar, This would be my 3rd day on Scheme so I'm still new with the grammar but I will try to make sense of what you gave me since it does work!

Comment: @Ceelos I wrote another solution using `peek-char`, you'll see that it's possible, but far more complex and harder to understand than my original solution.

Comment: Wow this is impressive. 
I traced it a bit and can see how it does the work. I will implement this concept in my code. Thanks again Oscar!

Comment: @Ceelos My pleasure!. Pleas don't forget to accept this answer as correct, if it was useful for you.